# MINRES implementation in Python

Tags: python, linear-algebra, solver

Is there any python implementation of MINRES pseudoinversion algorithm that can deal with Hermitian matrices?

I have found a few sources, but all of them are only capable of working with real matrices and do not seem to be easily generalizable onto the complex case:

https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/89958680/

https://github.com/pascanur/theano_optimize

(there are a couple of other links, but my reputation does not allow me to post them)

Comment: write your own? I'm too far out of university to to it myself, but I would definitely familiarize myself with numpy and numba if you want to make it execute fast. As far as low level compilation for python I've always found numba to be much friendlier (and sometimes faster too) to use than cython, and I've never tried anything like pypy..

Comment: it wouldn't be bad to implement your own, except if you need it right now (but all of us know [zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/))

Comment: We could probably give some advice if you could edit to provide a pseudocode algorithm, or help optimize if you have a semi-working script.

Comment: @Aaron I am a physicist, not programmer (and to be very honest I normally tend to avoid programming as long as it is possible), so making my own implementation is unfortunately not an option.

I am not sure what kind of pseudocode I can provide, - my question is simply whether there is a library with MINRES implementation for complex matrices that allows to work with user-defined matrix product.

What I can do, - I can provide a toy example of problem I wish to solve.

Comment: @user10998 I have not found one that handles complex numbers, nor do I understand the algorithm or it's implementation. You might take a stab at taking this problem over to the mathematics SE and ask how (or if) it would be possible to separate the real and imaginary components, compute using an existing implementation, then re-combine.

Comment: I seem to remember solving this by embedding the complex-valued matrices into (larger) real-valued ones, then using one of the standard Krylov subspace algorithms in scipy for real-valued ones. Does that sound like something that might work? I can't remember if I ever got my solution working.

Answer (score 0):

A Hermitian system of size $n$

$$\mathbf y = \mathbf H^{-1}\mathbf v$$

can be embedded in a real, symmetric system of size $2n$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Re(\mathbf y)\\Im(\mathbf y)
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\Re(\mathbf H)&-\Im(\mathbf H)\\Im(\mathbf H)&\Re(\mathbf H)
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Re(\mathbf v)\\Im(\mathbf v)
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Minimum-residual methods are often used for large problems, where constructing $H$ is impractical. In which case we may have an operation which computes a matrix-vector product, $f: \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^n; ,, f(\mathbf v) = \mathbf H\mathbf v.$ This function can be wrapped to operate on $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^{2n}$ by converting $\mathbf x$ back to a complex vector, applying $f$, and then embedding the result back in $\mathbb R^{2n}$.

Here is an example in python / numpy / scipy:

```py
from scipy.sparse.linalg import minres, LinearOperator
from pylab import *

# Problem size
N = 100

# error helper
er = lambda t,a,b:print('%s error:'%t,mean(abs(a-b)))

# random Hermitian matrix
Q = randn(N,N) + 1j*randn(N,N)
H = Q@conj(Q.T)

# random complex vector
v = randn(N) + 1j*randn(N)

# ground-truth solution
x0 = inv(H)@v

# Pack/unpack complex vector as stacked real vector
c2r = lambda v:block([real(v),imag(v)])
r2c = lambda v:kron([1,1j],eye(N))@v

# Verify that we can embed C^n in R^(2N)
Hr = real(H)
Hi = imag(H)
Hs = block([[Hr,-Hi],[Hi,Hr]])
vs = c2r(v)
xs = inv(Hs)@vs
x1 = r2c(xs)
er('Embed',x0,x1)

# Verify that minres works as expected in R-embed
x2 = r2c(minres(Hs,vs,tol=1e-12)[0])
er('Minres 1',x0,x2)

# Demonstrate using operators
Av = lambda u:c2r( H @ r2c(u) )
A  = LinearOperator((N*2,)*2,Av,Av)

# Minres, converting input/output to/from complex/real
x3 = r2c(minres(Hs,vs,tol=1e-12)[0])
er('Minres 2',x0,x3)
```

```
>>> Embed error: 5.317184726020268e-12
>>> Minres 1 error: 6.641342200989796e-11
>>> Minres 2 error: 6.641342200989796e-11
```